# Error in importing dbus in python on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, python, d-bus

I am trying to import dbus in a python script. But I am getting the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "playSong.py", line 4, in <module>
    import os, dbus
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dbus'
```

I have already installed the dbus. But still it is giving the error.
Why is this so?

Answer (score 0):

I tried installing using the following line and it worked.

```
conda install -c scottwales dbus-python
```